# Lucene adding additional filter returns no results

Tags: c#, search, lucene, lucene.net

I am attempting query some results using a Boolean Query. However the query does not return any results.

Here is the FilterQuery I am running. This returns no results, even though the field foo contains bar, and the field foo3 contains bar3. And I have triple checked my fields to make sure that the fields do exist in the index.

```
+(foo:bar foo2:bar2) +foo3:bar3
```

Now, If I remove the +foo3:bar3 from the query I get results back correctly. Also foo3:bar3 is being added programatically, so I am not parsing it. Here is some relevant code

```
//This code creates the first part of the query.
MultiFieldQueryParser mfqp = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29,SearchFields, analyzer);
Query q = mfqp.Parse(query);
BooleanQuery filterquery = new BooleanQuery();
filterquery.Add(q,BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

//This code creates the second part of the query
Query fq = new TermQuery(new Term("foo3","bar3"));
filterquery.Add(fq, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

//Perform the search
ScoreDoc[] hits = isearch.Search(filterquery, null, ResultsToReturn).scoreDocs;
```

Just for reference, I am current setting the fields to be analyzed, and the vector is set to With_positions_offsets

Comment: does +foo3:bar3 by itself return any documents?

Comment: It does return documents, if I modify the way the search works. If the MFQP passes in the term to the booleanquery then it works. but if I use the termquery, it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed from using a TermQuery, to using a QueryParser, which seems to have fixed the issue.